# LC Technology Relay x4 Reset to Mode 1?

Tags: esp8266

Hi have a LC Technology Relay x4 board with a custom-firmware (using ESPHome) on the ESP01 attached to it.

As a curiosity, I pressed on the S1 switch to see if it's doing something. The "normal" red led indicating MODE 1 turned off and the "MODE 2" blue led turned on. I found the meaning of those LEDs from documentation like [this one](https://manuals.plus/lc/lc-5v-2-channel-wifi-relay-module-esp01-manual).

My question is very very simple: How could I make my board returning to "Mode 1"? It seems the Mode 2 is doing something totally different and the board is not responding anymore to UART commands activating the relay.

I have the quad 12V model, but it's the same for all variant of this bord (dual or 5V versions).

Board design:
[image]

Comment: press the mode switch again

Comment: if the board has custom firmware, then the mode switch may not function as you expect

Comment: It is as I bought it... Is there somewhere I can find the right firmware to flash it?

Answer (score 2):

Hold the mode switch while powering the module on. It then selects mode 1 again.